# opencv write into a file the pixel values of binary image

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to ask question about on how to export/write all the pixel values into a txt file or other format that can be opened by notepad for example. Below the program.

Thanks, HB

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("MyImg.png");
  CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(img->height,img->width,CV_32FC3 );
  cvConvert( img, mat );
  outFile.open("MyFile.txt");

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
  {
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
      /// Get the (i,j) pixel value
      CvScalar scal = cvGet2D( mat,j,i);
      printf( "(%.f,%.f,%.f)",scal.val[0], scal.val[1],scal.val[2] );
    }

    printf("\n");
  }

  waitKey(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: btw, please **do not** use opencv's no more maintained c-api.

Comment: First look at some example of std::ofstream

Answer (score 2):

The class `Mat` of the new *OpenCV C++ API* is preferred over `IplImage` because it simplifies your code: [read more](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html) about the class `Mat`. For more information about loading an image, you could read [Load, Modify, and Save an Image](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html).

In order to write a text file using C++, you could use the class [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/)

Here is the source code.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat colorImage = imread("MyImg.png");

    // First convert the image to grayscale.
    Mat grayImage;
    cvtColor(colorImage, grayImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    // Then apply thresholding to make it binary.
    Mat binaryImage(grayImage.size(), grayImage.type());
    threshold(grayImage, binaryImage, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    // Open the file in write mode.
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("MyFile.txt");

    // Iterate through pixels.
    for (int r = 0; r < binaryImage.rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < binaryImage.cols; c++)
        {
            int pixel = binaryImage.at<uchar>(r,c);

            outputFile << pixel << '\t';
        }
        outputFile << endl;
    }

    // Close the file.
    outputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would like to know how opencv compute the area and the length of an image pixel by using contourArea and arcLength, see snapshot file for an example and what means these values.

Comment: If you want to ask another question, please ask a new question.